# An AES Cryptography Wrapper

Tags: c#, cryptography, aes

I built this wrapper over the System.Security.Cryptography.Aes encryption/decryption so that one need only instance the class and call the appropriate methods. This makes it much simpler to work with AES encryption so that developers don't need to reuse the same AES code everywhere they need encryption.

Any and all comments are much appreciated.

```
/// <summary>
/// Provides Cryptography methods based on AES cryptography implementation.
/// </summary>
public class AesCrypto
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the salt to use with AES encryption.
    /// </summary>
    public byte[] Salt { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the passphrase for use with AES encryption.
    /// </summary>
    public string Passphrase { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructs a new instance of <see cref="AesCrypto"/> from the specified values.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="salt">The <see cref="Salt"/> used in encryption.</param>
    /// <param name="passphrase">The <see cref="Passphrase"/> used in encryption.</param>
    public AesCrypto(byte[] salt, string passphrase)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(passphrase))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"The parameter {nameof(passphrase)} is required.");
        }

        if (salt == null || salt.Length == 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"The parameter {nameof(salt)} is required.");
        }

        Salt = salt;
        Passphrase = passphrase;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Uses AES encryption to encrypt a string of data.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="clearText">The data to encrypt. Data is expected to be Unicode.</param>
    /// <returns>An encrypted Base64 string.</returns>
    public string AesEncrypt(string clearText)
    {
        byte[] clearBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(clearText);

        using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
        {
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(Passphrase, Salt);
            encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
            encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length);
                    cs.Close();
                }

                clearText = StringExtensions.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
            }
        }

        return clearText;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Uses AES encryption to decrypt a string of data.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="cipherText">The encrypted Base64 string to decrypt.</param>
    /// <param name="Passphrase">The secret pre-shared passphrase.</param>
    /// <param name="throwExceptions">If true, will throw exceptions on decryption failure. Else, returns null string on decryption failure.</param>
    /// <returns>The plaintext data. Data is unicode.</returns>
    public string AesDecrypt(string cipherText, bool throwExceptions)
    {
        if (throwExceptions)
        {
            cipherText = AesDecryptInternal(cipherText);
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                cipherText = AesDecryptInternal(cipherText);
            }
            catch
            {
                cipherText = null;
            }
        }

        return cipherText;
    }

    private string AesDecryptInternal(string cipherText)
    {
        byte[] cipherBytes = StringExtensions.FromBase64String(cipherText);

        using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
        {
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes saltDerived = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(Passphrase, Salt);
            encryptor.Key = saltDerived.GetBytes(32);
            encryptor.IV = saltDerived.GetBytes(16);

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length);
                    cs.Close();
                }

                cipherText = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray());
            }
        }

        return cipherText;
    }
}
```

Comment: How does the decrypter learn which salt the encrypter used? I don't see you storing it alongside the ciphertext.

Comment: @CodesInChaos The developer is responsible for storing that. That's why I made a `Salt` property, the developer just needs to save the `Salt` somewhere. I didn't find it necessary to embed the salt with the result.

Comment: Implementing proper salt/IV management is at least half of the work of implementing symmetric crypto, so your code doesn't help the developer much. For example an uneducated developer might choose to use the same salt to encrypt more than one message.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I suppose it wouldn't be *hard* to embed the IV or a random salt within the encrypted string.

Comment: Usually the IV is transmitted with the message, and your heuristic here uses the IV as the first 16 bytes of the key, since both of them use the same salt with PBKDF2, reducing your AES256 to AES128.  Though really the IV should just be randomly generated, not computed.  You encrypt, transmit [random IV][ciphertext], then on decrypt read the first block as IV, then the rest as ciphertext.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
> public string AesEncrypt(string clearText)
> {
>     byte[] clearBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(clearText);
>
>     using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
>     {
>         Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(Passphrase, Salt);
>         encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
>         encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
>
>         using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
>         {
>             using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
>             {
>                 cs.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length);
>                 cs.Close();
>             }
>
>             clearText = StringExtensions.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
>         }
>     }
>
>     return clearText;
> }
> ```

- the call of the `Close()` method isn't needed, because the disposing of the `CryptoStream` will close the stream ([See the source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/cryptostream.cs,3bb570e73c03705d,references)).
- Instead of calling `ms.ToArray()` you should use the `MemoryStream.GetBuffer()` method to avoid having a copy of the byte array.

The same is true for the `AesDecryptInternal()` method.

- because `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` is inheriting `DerivedBytes` which is implementing `IDisposable` you should enclose it in an `using` block too.

The conditions when you throw an `ArgumentException`in the constructor aren't sufficient. The call to the `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` constructor will throw if the `Salt` isn't at least 8 bytes long. So checking against `salt.Length < 8` should be done.

In addition to whats being said about the length of the `Salt`, you should consider to have a backing field for the `Salt` property so you can change the property to have the same validation there. This will be true for the `Passphrase` property too.

Answer (score 3):

This feels a little clumsy:

```
public string AesDecrypt(string cipherText, bool throwExceptions)
{
    if (throwExceptions)
    {
        cipherText = AesDecryptInternal(cipherText);
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            cipherText = AesDecryptInternal(cipherText);
        }
        catch
        {
            cipherText = null;
        }
    }

    return cipherText;
}
```

I suggest an exception filter instead:

```
public string AesDecrypt(string cipherText, bool throwExceptions)
{
    try
    {
        return AesDecryptInternal(cipherText);
    }
    catch when (!throwExceptions)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

You can also combine the two methods now.

Comment: I never knew you could use `catch` like that, is that new to C#6.0?

Comment: Yes, it's a new and often overlooked feature of C# 6